# Rails application record model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this schema:

[image]

I would get the all item in price table where article classification have id 1.

How can I express this query through rails application record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your Price table `belongs_to` the Article table and each Article only `has_one` price you can do the following "belongs_to has_one" relationship query:

`Article.find(1).price.value    ##the 'price' method is made available by specifying the association with the Article model in Article.rb`

In `article.rb`

```
  has_one :price
```

In `'price.rb'`

```
belongs_to :article
```

To have the price method available on your article table you must specify the relationship in the Article and Price models.  Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html,more specifically for your case the has_one and belongs_to relationships.

Comment: I would the "articleClassification.id" from a price. For example, i would a code like this: "Price.article_classification(1)" ...

Comment: You need to look at some tutorials to understand why you'd do what I told you to.  For article_classification you can do:    Article.find(1).article_classification.id